# Пробный период платных виджетов в Android приложении

Tags: android, google-play

Есть желание сделать платный функционал приложения с пробным периодом (72 часа). Естественно, нужно чтобы он предоставлялся только после первого запуска приложения, а в дальнейшем была возможность его приобрести. Если кто-то шарит в этой теме, распишите примерно как это реализуется, можно ли как-то идентифицировать кокнертный аккаунт (или лучше устройство, ведь с одного аккаунта можно пользоваться несколькими устройствами) на котором установлено приложение, и что первый запуск уже состоялся - пробный период был предоставлен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нет бэка подключайте firebase. Там подключаете fireStore (БД) - при первом запуске сохраняете ID устройства и дату. При дальнейших запусках проверяете, есть ли в базе ID этого устройства, если нет - значит это новый юзер. Если есть, проверяете время записи + 72 часа. Как-то так